Passing Parameters to a .c executed with execl in C
In C, if I use the execl command to execute another .c file, is there a way to pass parameters to this file that it can use during execution?
In my problem, I have C code that uses execl to execute an additional .c script. Once this script completes execution and returns its output (written to a file for context), control returns to the main file.
To avoid issues with the second script reading files, I’d like to perform as many operations as possible in the main code and then pass only the results to the second process via parameter passing. Is there a way for these two pieces of code to communicate?
execl("./script", "script", argcv[i], NULL);


That's exactly how you pass parameters -- put them in the argument list of execl().

Note that execl() never returns, it doesn't return control to the original program. It replaces the program in the current process with the program being exec'ed. If you want to keep the original program running, you need to use fork() to execute the second progam in a child process.

@barmar So, by inserting the values instead of NULL, will they behave like variables already present in the second file?

They'll be in the argv of the new program.

Basically it's execl("./script", "script", arg1, arg2, ..., (char*)NULL);

And if you need to generate the argument list dynamically, with different numbers of arguments, use execv().

Google "execl execv tutorial"

Note that if execl() succeeds, it does not return; if it returns, it failed.  That means there's no need to test the returned value (it will always be -1).  But you should have code to handle an error return (print an error message and exit with a failure status, probably).
